# Where to handle "child" pop-up, IceFaces?

Tags: icefaces

I'm new to maintaining legacy code, and I'm patient to learn. At the moment I need to 1) add a button to a pop-up that shows person's data, and the button should wait, 2) on click I need new pop-up to change the name of the person. I have some back-end methods, I placed the button, and I am getting both pop-ups at the same time. I don't know where to place panelPopUp, or how to handle button's listener. Any suggestions? Thank you

Kind wishes

I made a several methods (Java 1.7) in a bean, similar to some existing examples. I messed with xhtml...